# CLR APTCA Share mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, clr

I am getting the following output in the debug window of Visaul Studio 2015 Update 1 when I run my MVC 4 application.

Cant say I've seen it before... Is this normal, should I be concerned?

`CLR:(C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll) Rejecting code sharing because a dependent assembly did not match the conditional APTCA share mode
CLR:(C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll) Rejecting code sharing because a dependent assembly did not match the conditional APTCA share mode
CLR:(C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll) Rejecting code sharing because a dependent assembly did not match the conditional APTCA share mode`

Comment: I can't escape these now. Hate em.. Feels like symbol loading has taken over my startups.

Answer (score 2):

Go into your web project properties page, on the "Web" tab down under "Debuggers", uncheck "Native Code"

Then weep with joy and relief as your launch time goes from a torment to a wickedly fast, no extra lines breaks in your output window JOY.

8)

Comment: Note to self: don't touch the checkbox if you don't know what it means.